# Vector of shared_ptr of an class C++

Tags: c++, oop, vector, smart-pointers

as the title says I want to declare a vector from shared_ptr of a class.
This is class member.

Deklaration of class header:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<connection>>RemoteVerbindungen;
```

usage in the class:

```
  RemoteVerbindungen.push_back(std::shared_ptr<connection>(new connection(SERVICE_SOCKET)));      
  //Iterator positionieren
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<connection>>::iterator VerbindungsNr = RemoteVerbindungen.begin();
```

Also from the class, here the access to the method does not work, if you use the iterator or the direct access via 0.

```
RemoteVerbindungen[0]->startUp();
RemoteVerbindungen[VerbindungsNr]->startUp();
```

the member method "starUp" is not executed.
The access to "RemoteConnections" Vector is not possible via the iterator. Compiler error type conversion not possible.

Do I create the new ptr under the vector pointing to a newly created object of type "connection"?

Comment: You tell us, it's unclear what you even mean with "does not work". Please provide a [mcve] and clarify the problem

Comment: I hope the question or problem is better formulated

Comment: Well, the second part is because you are using the iterator wrong. An iterator is not an index, it's more like a pointer to an element. The first question is still unclear because you haven't provided a [mcve] or shown what you expect to happen (and how you determined the function isn't called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer `std::make_shared()` instead of using `new` manually:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<connection>> RemoteVerbindungen;
...
RemoteVerbindungen.push_back(std::make_shared<connection>(SERVICE_SOCKET));
```

And, prefer `auto` when declaring and initializing the iterator in the same statement:

```cpp
auto VerbindungsNr = RemoteVerbindungen.begin();
```

Now, that being said, `RemoteVerbindungen[0]->startUp();` should work just fine, if the `vector` is not empty, and the `shared_ptr` at index 0 is not set to `nullptr`.

However, `RemoteVerbindungen[VerbindungsNr]->startUp();` is definitely wrong, as an iterator is not an index.  You need to dereference the iterator to access the `shared_ptr` that it refers to, and then you can use `shared_ptr::operator->` to access the members of the `connection` object, eg:

```cpp
(*VerbindungsNr)->startUp();
```